# How to debug slow performance on IIS?

Tags: php, sql-server, iis

My local development site runs very slowly.  Pages that are not cached in my application take 15-45 seconds to load, and pages that are cached take around 5 seconds to load.  (The application is a Drupal site and ordinarily I would host it on Linux, but in this case I absolutely have to use IIS.)

When I look at the Network tab of my browser's Web Tools, I see it is the initial request of the document that is very slow.  Once the HTML document loads, all other assets load very quickly.  I do not see the same slow performance with a flat HTML file, so the issue might have to do with PHP or SQL Server.

How can I narrow down the cause of the problem?

My version info:

```
PHP 8.1.21 with opcache enabled
Windows 10
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB5021125) - 15.0.2101.7 (X64)
```

Comment: My first guess would be to see if opcache is enabled for PHP

Comment: @ChrisHaas  opcache is enabled.  I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: Enable FRT (use 200-999 in this case) to see how the time is spent on each steps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/troubleshoot-php-with-failed-request-tracing If you can see PHP itself is slow, profiling is your next step.

Comment: You can use xdebug profiling to find bottlenecks.

Comment: It sounds like your origin server is slow or overloaded. If your website is static, you can create a cache configuration to cache HTML pages. Otherwise, you need to make sure your server responds faster. You should also check your server logs for any anomalies.

Comment: Though it doesn't address my original "How to debug" question, I identified the problem in my case.  I needed to download the latest cacert.pem as described here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2481341 -- This has resolved multiple problems with my site and it is now blazing fast -- at least for the moment.

Comment: Two months later, the problem has returned.  Exact same problem.  This time downloading the latest cacert.pem has made no difference.

Comment: Update: I was able to resolve the latest performance problem by switching from a remote database to a local one.